# How to know the name of interface for WiFi DIRECT in android?

Tags: android, linux, networking, wifi, wifi-direct

I need to know what is the name of wireless interface for WiFi direct at android platform.

It seems that `wlan0` is the most common interface used, but how exactly do i know it ?

I saw this answer on `stackoverflow` but is this for WiFi :

```
for(Enumeration<NetworkInterface> list = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); list.hasMoreElements();)
{
    NetworkInterface i = list.nextElement();
    Log.e("network_interfaces", "display name " + i.getDisplayName());
}
```